# Getting Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, list, data-structures

**Get error in this line "if (*L==NULL)" and my program is below.I'm practicing to create a list in C.**

```
enum Status List_Init(SqListPtr L)
{
    Status s = fail;
    Ptr p;
    if (*L==NULL)
    {
        p = (Ptr)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (p == NULL) return s;
        *L = p;
        (*L)->next = NULL;
        s = success;
    }
    return s;
}
```

**When I only use funcation List_init to init a  list, it is fine. But when I use funcation List_Create to actually create a list, it start to get this error in funcation List_Init.**

```
enum Status List_Create(SqListPtr L,ElemType Data[],int Len)
{
    enum Status s;
    Ptr p;
    s = List_Init(L);
    if (s==success) {
        for (int i = Len-1;i>=0 ;--i ) {
            p = (Ptr)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            if (p) {
                p->elem = Data[i];
                p->next = (*L)->next;
                (*L)->next = p;
            }
            else{
                s = fail;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

**And here is my main funcation.**

```
int main() {

    SqListPtr L;

    int len = 4;

    int Data[] = {1,2,3,4};

    enum Status s = List_Create(L, Data, len);

    printf("%d",s);

    return 0;
}
```

**And this is header file.**

```
typedef int ElemType;

typedef enum Status
{
    success = 1, fail = 0, fatal = -1, range_error = -2
}Status;

typedef struct Node
{
    ElemType elem;
    struct Node *next;
}Node, *Ptr;

typedef Ptr *SqListPtr;



enum Status List_Init(SqListPtr L);
enum Status List_Create(SqListPtr L,ElemType Data[],int Len);
```

Comment: Obviously `L` is NULL so it shouldn't be dereferenced. Can't tell you any more than that based on this incomplete code. If you need further help please post a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `SqListPtr L;` That is an uninitialised pointer. Which means it points to invalid memory and should not be dereferenced. You need to set it to point to a `struct Node` or to NULL and then change the code to handle NULL. Also, suggest you remove all the pointer typedefs - it's not good practice as it makes the code much harder to read.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks, It's helpful. God bless you.

Comment: @kaylum Is there any standard program to learn that you could suggest?(about list in c) I don't think mine is a good one.